# add filed automatically to form in dajngo CreateView

Tags: django, django-views, django-forms

I have Major model and Course model. when I add course to the course model using ModelForm and CreatView class, I want to add the field automatically.
I tried to use form_valid method but it get me this Error:
`NOT NULL constraint failed: quizes_course.major_id`
this is the major model:

```
class Major(models.Model):
    name   = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    years   = models.IntegerField(validators=[minMaxVal])

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("majors")
    

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "1. Majors"
```

and this is the course model:

```
class Course(models.Model):
    major   = models.ForeignKey(Major, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    year    = models.IntegerField(validators=[minMaxVal])
    name    = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.major.name}_{self.year}_{self.name}'

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("courses", kwargs={"pk": self.major.pk})
        
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "2. Courses"
```

and this is the view:

```
class CreateCourse(CreateView):
    model = Course
    form_class = CourseCreateForm 
    template_name = 'quizes/create.html'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.save(commit=False)
        major = get_object_or_404(Major, id=self.kwargs['pk'])
        form.major = major.id
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

Comment: "I want to add the field automatically..." add what field? your question isn't clear

Comment: Can you add your CourseCreateForm class please.
The issue is that your model has `major` as being a required field, I.E it does not allow NULLs. Therefore you need to include a value for it within your formset. You have a couple of options. 
1. set blank=True on the model field so that it's not required by the forms validation or 2. Set the value on the form when you initialise it and make it a hidden field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve this problem by overriding post method in the CreateCourse:

```
def post(self, request, pk):
        form = CourseCreateForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            major = get_object_or_404(Major, id=pk)
            form = form.cleaned_data
            course = Course(major=major, name=form['name'], year=form['year'])
            course.save()
            return redirect(reverse('courses', kwargs={'pk':pk}))
        return Http404('Error')
```